# Second Master in Finance Engineering (US)

Tags: masters, united-states, computer-science, finance

I hold a Bachelor degree in Computer Science from a top university (in Europe). I will finish soon a Master degree in Computer Science in another top university, but with a very strong focus on machine learning, data management and statistics. I have had a very strong interest for mathematics modeling and theoretical machine learning. But now I would like to move towards research in quantitative finance, preferably in the United States.

I am now wondering if it is worthwhile (and relevant) to apply for a second a Master degree in Finance Engineering in the US, or if it is better to try entering the industry directly without much experience in finance? I already have a few internship positions in machine learning research and data science area across Europe, would that help for a go-to market?

Any external thoughts are very welcome, thank you!

Comment: If you want to work in research, why not a doctorate?

Comment: @Buffy This is the tradeoff I am facing now. But as said in the post, I think I would like to move toward research in industry, more specifically in quantitative finance.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you want to work in the U.S.
If yes, and if you are not a U.S citizen, it is better to take a U.S master's degree, so that you can have an OPT visa to work in the U.S for 1-3 years(depending on your major)

But in my personal opinion, if you would like to work in the industry, not the academic field, I think you can enter the industry directly since it will make you understand what the industry needs, and what you lack. It is never too late to go back to school!

Comment: But how feasible is it to enter the quantitative finance industry in the US without a citizenship?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo This is also an open question to say real. I said the US only because of personal first thought or preferences, but London would also be a very good option in Europe i think. Do you have good threads or references discussing the pros/cons of US/UK for quant and finance?

Comment: @gnometorule Thank you for that, that's interesting. I really thought that it was hard to get into quant positions everywhere, but that it was especially competitive in the US... Both to get hired and pass the interviews, but also to get a visa sponsorship.